# error when using import command in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and now learning how to to import a module or a function, but I got these posted errors. The python code is saved under the name: `hello_module.py`

python code:

```
def hello_func():
    print ("Hello, World!")
hello_func()
import hello_module
hello_module.hello_func()
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/hello_module.py", line 9, in <module>
    import hello_module
  File "C:/Python33\hello_module.py", line 10, in <module>
    hello_module.hello_func()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hello_func'
```

Comment: import hello_module should not be in hello_module.py. it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot and should not import your own module. You defined `hello_func` in the *current* namespace, just use that directly.

You can put the function in a *separate* file, then import that:

- File `foo.py`:

  ```
  def def hello_func():
      print ("Hello, World!")
  ```
- File `bar.py`:

  ```
  import foo

  foo.hello_func()
  ```

and run `bar.py` as a script.

If you try to import your own module, it'll import *itself* again, and when you do that you import an *incomplete* module. It won't have it's attributes set yet, so `hello_module.hello_func` doesn't yet exist, and that breaks.